# Gitlab - See list of files deleted in a commit

Tags: git, gitlab

In Gitlab one can see diffs via the Changes tab on a commit. It very frequently shows

> Too many changes to show.  To preserve performance only 51 of 80 files
>   are displayed.

Thus, is there a way to just see say the list of files that were deleted in the commit vs having to scroll through the incomplete list of changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command line to view the deleted files:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

Use the `--diff-filter=D` and it will display list of deleted files

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

If you don't want all the information about which commit they were removed in, you can just add a grep delete in there.

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete
```